# FTP / File Manager system required

Tags: ftp, filesystems

I am looking for a third-party FTP/File Management system to integrate into a website that will allow:

-User accounts
-Ability to create folders and upload / download various types of files

Simple as that really, I am not sure on the terminology that helps searching for a system like this.  If anyone has used a decent service / script that would provide this type of functionality to integrate into an existing site then please let me know, many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Many web browsers have FTP capabilities built in.  If you redirect the user to an ftp:// address, it will prompt for a username and password and display the contents of the associated FTP folder.  IIRC, some older browsers (IE6, in particular) don't have upload capabilities, but more recent versions might.

Using the built-in FTP functionality would save some effort on that front, but you would still have the problem of user management.  Solving that problem might depend on your FTP server.  What FTP server software and OS are you running?

Comment: Thanks.  The browser solution would work OK, but I am looking to provide a user (client) with a link to a secure area where they can manage files - upload / download for other people who would also do the same.  I am not sure what FTP server software I am running - but the site will be served from a Rackspace server running Linux/Apache.

Comment: Looking through some options this seems pretty good: http://www.omnistardrive.com

Comment: If you are okay with a non-free solution, you might want to check out http://www.xythos.com.  My old university had that set up for students and it worked very well.  There is also http://www.box.net, but I have not tried it myself.

Comment: Thanks for that. If a good looking website is anything to go on, then Box looks really great, could be quite expensive though if you need more than 3 users (which I do).